# How to get total tether supply on Ethereum from BigQuery dataset

Tags: tokens, query, stablecoins

I've noticed that the numbers for Totaly supply of Tethers seem to diverge on the [official Tether transparency page](https://wallet.tether.to/transparency) and the [Etherscan block explorer](https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7), and I want to find a way to get the correct number.

At the time of writing the difference is:

- etherscan.io tether token tracker: $3,338,120,254.587539
- official tether webpage: $3,278,120,254.58

Obviously just one of this values is correct, so I tried to confirm either value with the [following query](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?sq=833033420226:f8f2b3207f0d4671939a110fe48d7d14) on the publicly available Big Query ethereum dataset:

```
SELECT
  sum(cast (value as numeric))
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data`.crypto_ethereum.token_transfers
WHERE
  block_number > 6000000
  AND token_address = '0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7'
  AND from_address = '0xc6cde7c39eb2f0f0095f41570af89efc2c1ea828'
  AND to_address = '0x5754284f345afc66a98fbb0a0afe71e0f007b949';
```

Where I assumed that the from_address must be the minting address '0xc6cde7c39eb2f0f0095f41570af89efc2c1ea828' and the to_address must be the tether treasury address '0x5754284f345afc66a98fbb0a0afe71e0f007b949'. Both found on Etherscan.
This query returned $3,180,008,005.642000 which is at the same level of precision as Etherscan token tracker, but is obviously not the same as either of two sources.

Do you know of a way to confirm the total supply of tether using the big query dataset? Perhaps some of my assumptions about minting or treasury addresses are wrong? I'd like to get as close as possible to the correct number, because it would be really interesting to monitor the real supply of tether in the coming months. And we should know the real number.